# WordPress Page Column Problem

Tags: posts, pages

The sidebar which should be on the right side is being loaded below the content. How do I move the sidebar to the default position?

Here's the [link](http://sweetpotatochronicles.com/new/test/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the extra class `row` wrapped.

After the `container` class

```
<div class="container">
```

Remove this code of class `row`

```
<div class="row">
```

and also remove the extra closing div if added for it.

The sidebar will be positioned to the right side.